# せいせいすらあ Meaning

Tags: colloquial-language, phrases, contractions, particle-わ, compensatory-lengthening

This is from the manga Kaiji. A hated character is making his departure, and Kaiji thinks to himself, "消えろ！消えろ！。。。！”　”せいせいすらあ。。。。”

The first part is pretty easy, basically like "Yeah, get outta here!"
But I can't figure out at all what the ”せいせいすらあ" means. There's tons of meanings for せいせい, and not having much like finding info in すらあ either.

Answer (score 6):

First of all,

> 「せいせい**すらあ**」

is a Tokyo tough guy's colloquial version of

> 「せいせい**するわ**」

(For those who still believe that 「わ」 is feminine, it is ***not***.)

Next, 「せいせいする」.　(「清々する」 using kanji.)

It is a set phrase expressing how one feels refreshed, relieved, etc. after a big problem has disappeared.  My own secret translation of the phrase would be:

> "***Good Riddance!***"

Comment: Inuyasha is saying あんな女…いねえ方がせいせいすらあ。  when Kagome, a girl that made him a lot of troubles, decided to disappear. She stole a precious item from him though and disappeared with it, so I don’t think that the feeling of relief is the correct interpretation here. Any idea what could that mean in this case?

Comment: Maybe I unscrambled it. Even though Kagome said she is going away, Inuyasha doesn’t know that she really managed to disappear. Moreover it looks like he is looking for her. The sentence can very well mean: “If that woman [Kagome] weren’t here, it would be much easier.” I wonder whether I’m not totally of here.